# url rewrites magento 1.7

Tags: magento, url

I change my url rewrites to remove the category out of the url for example

url/category/subcategory (before rewrite)

url/subcategory (after rewrite)

and everything works perfect but when I do index management they all regenerate back to default how do I stop it from changing them back to the original I want my new rewrite to stay it takes forever to bring them all back!

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Admin -> system -> Index management** -> select **catalog URL Rewrites** and change index mode to "Manual update". Thats it. You are done.

Comment: this does nothing if you click select all and click submit it re-generates everything? I want to disable this feature so client does not refresh hundreads of my urls.. Thanks!